# Is there a way to execute the stored string command in dplyr filter? with OR operator

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

I have a code where the column names are stored in string format in a list. What I am trying to do is filter the dataset with those column names using OR operator. In the example below I know the number of items in the list so I am able to run in single line using list index value.

I want to be able to run this in a function where the input could have unknown number of items in the column name list.

```
  iris
  len = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
    
  # this is what I am trying to do but with dynamic list  
  iris %>% filter(!!sym(len[[1]]) > 6 | !!sym(len[[2]]) > 6)
```

One thing I was thinking of was if I could store the command in string variable. Something like this

```
txt_new = ""
for (i in 1:length(len)) {
    txt = ""
    txt = paste0("!!sym(len[[",i ,"]]) > 6|")
    txt_new = paste0(txt_new, txt)
}
txt = substr(txt_new,1,nchar(txt_new)-1)
```

where eventually I would get `txt = "!!sym(len[[1]]) > 6 | !!sym(len[[2]]) > 6"`

But I would still need to put execute the string within filter which is also not working.

```
iris %>% filter(eval(txt))
```

Is there a way to accomplish this. Using a dynamic list of variable that needs to be used to filter a dataset with OR operator. If it was AND then it would be definitely be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way going along the path of what you were doing.

```r
len <- c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")

# create the txt string: "( Sepal.Length > 6) | ( Petal.Length > 6)"
txt <- paste(sapply(len, function(x) paste("(", x, "> 6)")), collapse = " | ")

library(dplyr)

# convert it to an expression and then evaluate it within filter
iris %>% 
  filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cur_data() like this:

```
iris %>% filter(cur_data()[[len[1]]] > 6 & cur_data()[[len[2]]] > 6)
```

or dot:

```
iris %>% filter(.[[len[1]]] > 6 & .[[len[2]]] > 6)
```